# Not able to consume ActiveMQ message on tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, jms, activemq-classic, jndi

I am trying to configure Apache Active MQ in Apache Tomcat. I have two war files, MessageProducer.war and MessageConsumer.war.I have added all the ActiveMQ dependency jars in /WebContent/WEB-INF/lib folder of both projects. I have added following Resources configured in context.xml files of both wars. And context.xml file is placed inside /WebContent/META-INF/ folder for both wars.

Context.xml

```
<Context>
<Resource
        name="myConFactory"
        auth="Container"
        type="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory"
        description="JMS Connection Factory"
        factory="org.apache.activemq.jndi.JNDIReferenceFactory"
        brokerURL="vm://localhost"
        brokerName="LocalActiveMQBroker"
        useEmbeddedBroker="true"/>

 <Resource name="jms/myTopic"
          auth="Container"
          type="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTopic"
          factory="org.apache.activemq.jndi.JNDIReferenceFactory"
          physicalName="com.myproject.TOPIC"/>
 </Context>
```

Entries related to ActiveMQ are configured in web.xml file as below for both the wars.

web.xml

```
<resource-env-ref>
<resource-env-ref-name>myConFactory</resource-env-ref-name>
<resource-env-ref-type>org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory</resource-env-ref-type>
</resource-env-ref>     
<resource-env-ref>
<resource-env-ref-name>jms/myTopic</resource-env-ref-name>
<resource-env-ref-type>org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTopic</resource-env-ref-type>
</resource-env-ref>
```

MessageProducer.java file in MessageProducer.war, will publish messages to Topic. Below is the code for the same:

```
try {
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
             "org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory");
props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"vm://localhost");
Context context = new InitialContext(props);
TopicConnectionFactory factory = (TopicConnectionFactory) 
context.lookup("java:comp/env/myConFactory");
TopicConnection connection = factory.createTopicConnection();
session = connection.createTopicSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
Topic topic = (Topic) context.lookup("java:comp/env/jms/myTopic");
publisher = session.createPublisher(topic);
TextMessage tm = session.createTextMessage();
tm.setText("Sending Message with ActiveMQ");
publisher.publish(tm);
}
catch(Exceptione e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have deployed MessageProducer.war on Tomcat v7.

MessageConsumer.java file is in MessageConsumer.war, will consume messages published by MessageProducer. Below is the code for the same:

```
public class MessageConsumer extends HttpServlet  {
public TopicSession session = null;
public TopicConnection connection = null;
Topic topic = null;
TopicSubscriber subscriber = null;

    public void init() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
            "org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory");
    props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "vm://localhost");
    Context context = null;
    try {
        context = new InitialContext(props);
        TopicConnectionFactory factory = null;
        factory = (TopicConnectionFactory) context.
        lookup("java:comp/env/myConFactory");
        connection = factory.createTopicConnection();
        connection.setClientID("DURABLE_SUBSCRIBER_ID");
        session = connection.createTopicSession(false,
        Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        topic = (Topic) context.lookup("java:comp/env/jms/myTopic");
        subscriber = session.createDurableSubscriber(topic, 
        "DURABLE_SUBSCRIBER");
        connection.start();
        TextMessage tm = (TextMessage) subscriber.receive(3000);
        String strMsgRecieved = tm.getText();
    } catch (NamingException | JMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
 }
```

I have configured MessageConsumer class to run on StartUp in web.xml as below.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>startupServelt</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.myproject.MessageConsumer</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

I have deployed MessageConsumer.war on Tomcat v8. Both Tomcat v7 and v8 are running on same physical machine and same JVM. When I start MessageProducer.war runnning, it publishes messages to Topic which I can see through JConsole. But when I start MessageConsumer war, it will show Starting Apache Tomcat 100%, for infinite time. It won't proceed. It won't show any exception or anything on Tomcat console.And It won't consume the message published. Please let me know what am I doing wrong or why its not working.

Answer (score 2):

> Both Tomcat v7 and v8 are running on same physical machine and same
>   JVM.

I am not sure of how can two Tomcat instances run on the same JVM. They can use the same JDK, yes, and they can run on the same physical machine too but they won't be on the same JVM. They would both launch their own JVM, independent of each other.

In your case you are using the ActiveMQ embedded broker, which, as per the documentation [here](http://activemq.apache.org/vm-transport-reference.html), allows "clients to connect to each other inside the VM". In your case, I think, it is not the same VM. The message consumer which is looking for the message is looking at a different instance of ActiveMQ than what the message producer is sending the message to.

Comment: No. For both the Tomcats I have configured JRE8 to be used by default. So both use same JVM.

Comment: @BabannaDuggani AdityaK has completely right, you had configured your tomcats to use JRE8 version but this is not mean the same JVM !

Comment: @BabannaDuggani If you use the same JRE for two different environments, it does not mean that you are using the same JVM! Each server instance will spawn its own JVM and they will work independently of each other. They will be two separate processes at the OS level. That is what is happening in your case too.

Answer (score 1):

it's ok for load-on-startup.

your `startupServelt` will listen for only one message on startup, you need to loop over `subscriber.receive(3000);` in another thread or use a `MessageListener`.

hava you any other logs of tomcat startup or activemq.

you say : **For both the Tomcats I have configured JRE8 to be used by default. So both use same JVM** !! 
So both use same JVM version but not the same running JVM.
 i think here is the problem, MessageConsumer.war is running on Tomcat v8 and consume messages from AMQ on v8 and MessageProducer.war on Tomcat v7 and send messages to AMQ on v7. for this reason everything is ok you can see producer producing messages but consumer receive nothing since it is in another JVM than producer and there is no producer to send messages to their broker !!

you need to deploy your 2 applications on the same Tomcat to make it working.

Comment: I agree with your comment that, startupServlet will consume only one message during startUp. I need to loop over to keep on consuming. But in my case its not even consuming the first message. It simply keeps on displaying message at the bottom of eclipse, "Starting Up Tomcat Server 100%". There is no exception on console.

Comment: there is no reason to have an exception since you load on startup 0 instances of startupServelt !! change  <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup> to  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> or call the startupServelt by a http request to start it.

Comment: How are you sure that the two Apache instances are running on the same JVM?

Comment: @AdityaK where did you seen that i was sure that the two Apache instances are running on the same JVM?

Comment: @HassenBennour I was addressing Babanna Duggani. Sorry I should have been more clear. I mistakenly added that as a comment to your answer. I should have put that as a comment to the question.

Comment: Here <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup> , means startupServlet is the first one to be loaded by the container. '0' here specifies the order. If you have two or more servlets to be loaded by container on Startup, then the servlet with value '0' will be loaded first, then the servlet with value '1' and then with value '2' and so on.

Comment: @BabannaDuggani Please be mindful of the fact that I was the first to point this out, as reflected in my answer and comments.

Comment: @AdityaK i agree no problems.